# Summing columns contents in a multi index dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[Dataframe sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCA5p.png)

I have this multi- index data frame with multi level columns and indices. For the columns, the highest level is the floors (ground floor- first floor..etc) and then the next level is apartments and finally the rooms. In the rooms level I have for each room 7 columns **[1_B4_QHEAT-, 1_B4_QCOOL+, 1_B4_QINF+, 1_B4_QVENT+,    1_B4_QTRANS+,   1_B4_QGINT+,    1_B4_QSOL+]**.
The number in the beginning of the title is the room number and it goes from 1 to 67. Is there a way to sum the contents of each similar columns for each apartment without having to do it manually?
Example: I want to automate:

```
df['Qcool_apt1'] = df['1_B4_QCOOL+'] + df['2_B4_QCOOL+'] + df['3_B4_QCOOL+']
df['Qcool_apt2'] = df['4_B4_QCOOL+'] + df['5_B4_QCOOL+'] + df['6_B4_QCOOL+']
```

Thanks

Part of the source code of the dataframe: `df.head().to_dict()`

```
{('G.F', 'G.F_apt1', '1_B4_QHEAT-'): {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 3.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 4.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 5.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 6.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 7.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 8.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 9.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 10.0): 0.0},
 ('G.F', 'G.F_apt1', '1_B4_QCOOL+'): {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 3.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 4.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 5.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 6.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 7.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 8.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 9.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 10.0): 0.0},
 ('G.F', 'G.F_apt1', '1_B4_QINF+'): {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0): -0.010019444444444444,
  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0): -0.012180555555555556,
  (1.0, 1.0, 3.0): -0.01233611111111111,
  (1.0, 1.0, 4.0): -0.012338888888888889,
  (1.0, 1.0, 5.0): -0.013033333333333334,
  (1.0, 1.0, 6.0): -0.013419444444444446,
  (1.0, 1.0, 7.0): -0.013686111111111112,
  (1.0, 1.0, 8.0): -0.014041666666666666,
  (1.0, 1.0, 9.0): -0.013361111111111112,
  (1.0, 1.0, 10.0): -0.011313888888888887},
 ('G.F', 'G.F_apt1', '1_B4_QVENT+'): {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0): -0.05011111111111111,
  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0): -0.06088888888888889,
  (1.0, 1.0, 3.0): -0.06169444444444444,
  (1.0, 1.0, 4.0): -0.06169444444444444,
  (1.0, 1.0, 5.0): -0.06516666666666666,
  (1.0, 1.0, 6.0): -0.06708333333333333,
  (1.0, 1.0, 7.0): -0.06841666666666667,
  (1.0, 1.0, 8.0): -0.07022222222222223,
  (1.0, 1.0, 9.0): -0.06680555555555556,
  (1.0, 1.0, 10.0): -0.05655555555555555},
 ('G.F', 'G.F_apt1', '1_B4_QTRANS+'): {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0): -0.26725,
  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0): -0.2573333333333333,
  (1.0, 1.0, 3.0): -0.25233333333333335,
  (1.0, 1.0, 4.0): -0.2554166666666667,
  (1.0, 1.0, 5.0): -0.2500277777777778,
  (1.0, 1.0, 6.0): -0.24869444444444444,
  (1.0, 1.0, 7.0): -0.15308333333333335,
  (1.0, 1.0, 8.0): -0.18811111111111112,
  (1.0, 1.0, 9.0): -0.10619444444444445,
  (1.0, 1.0, 10.0): -0.11352777777777777},
 ('G.F', 'G.F_apt1', '1_B4_QGINT+'): {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0): 0.32861111111111113,
  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0): 0.32861111111111113,
  (1.0, 1.0, 3.0): 0.32861111111111113,
  (1.0, 1.0, 4.0): 0.32861111111111113,
  (1.0, 1.0, 5.0): 0.32861111111111113,
  (1.0, 1.0, 6.0): 0.32861111111111113,
  (1.0, 1.0, 7.0): 0.23591666666666666,
  (1.0, 1.0, 8.0): 0.23591666666666666,
  (1.0, 1.0, 9.0): 0.058583333333333334,
  (1.0, 1.0, 10.0): 0.058583333333333334},
 ('G.F', 'G.F_apt1', '1_B4_QSOL+'): {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0): 1.1119444444444444e-15,
  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0): 3.0916666666666665e-15,
  (1.0, 1.0, 3.0): 7.061111111111111e-16,
  (1.0, 1.0, 4.0): 8.877777777777779e-17,
  (1.0, 1.0, 5.0): 1.1541666666666667e-15,
  (1.0, 1.0, 6.0): -1.7122222222222222e-15,
  (1.0, 1.0, 7.0): 4.913888888888889e-17,
  (1.0, 1.0, 8.0): 0.035083333333333334,
  (1.0, 1.0, 9.0): 0.11869444444444445,
  (1.0, 1.0, 10.0): 0.13019444444444445},
 ('G.F', 'G.F_apt1', '2_B4_QHEAT-'): {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 3.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 4.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 5.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 6.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 7.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 8.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 9.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 10.0): 0.0},
 ('G.F', 'G.F_apt1', '2_B4_QCOOL+'): {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 3.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 4.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 5.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 6.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 7.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 8.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 9.0): 0.0,
  (1.0, 1.0, 10.0): 0.0},
 ('G.F', 'G.F_apt1', '2_B4_QINF+'): {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0): -0.014025000000000001,
  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0): -0.01704722222222222,
  (1.0, 1.0, 3.0): -0.017252777777777777,
  (1.0, 1.0, 4.0): -0.017258333333333334,
  (1.0, 1.0, 5.0): -0.01822222222222222,
  (1.0, 1.0, 6.0): -0.018758333333333335,
  (1.0, 1.0, 7.0): -0.019163888888888887,
  (1.0, 1.0, 8.0): -0.019674999999999998,
  (1.0, 1.0, 9.0): -0.01864722222222222,
  (1.0, 1.0, 10.0): -0.01573888888888889},
 ('G.F', 'G.F_apt1', '2_B4_QVENT+'): {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0): -0.07011111111111111,
  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0): -0.08522222222222223,
  (1.0, 1.0, 3.0): -0.08627777777777779,
  (1.0, 1.0, 4.0): -0.08630555555555555,
  (1.0, 1.0, 5.0): -0.09111111111111111,
  (1.0, 1.0, 6.0): -0.09380555555555556,
  (1.0, 1.0, 7.0): -0.09580555555555555,
  (1.0, 1.0, 8.0): -0.09838888888888889,
  (1.0, 1.0, 9.0): -0.09322222222222223,
  (1.0, 1.0, 10.0): -0.07869444444444444},
 ('G.F', 'G.F_apt1', '2_B4_QTRANS+'): {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0): -0.3169444444444444,
  (1.0, 1.0, 2.0): -0.30416666666666664,
  (1.0, 1.0, 3.0): -0.29638888888888887,
  (1.0, 1.0, 4.0): -0.3013888888888889,
  (1.0, 1.0, 5.0): -0.29333333333333333,
  (1.0, 1.0, 6.0): -0.29194444444444445,
  (1.0, 1.0, 7.0): -0.21258333333333332,
  (1.0, 1.0, 8.0): -0.2489722222222222,
  (1.0, 1.0, 9.0): -0.0888611111111111,
  (1.0, 1.0, 10.0): -0.0931111111111111},
```

Comment: kindly share the source code for the dataframe : ``df.head().to_dict()``

Comment: @sammywemmy Thanks I added it to the question.

Comment: apologies. busy with some other task. Could you kindly explain what the pattern is? cant make out what the pattern difference is between `Q..1` and `Q..2`